# Matching Requirements to a Rational Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

On a precalculus test I got recently, the following question stumped the entire class, and even weeks later, none of us could figure it out!
The problem is to

> Write the equation of the following rational function, given this information:
>
> Domain: $x\neq -0.5, \ 5,6$
>
> $f(0) = 8$
>
> $f(3) = 0$
>
> $f(-8) = 0$
>
> $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 4$
>
> $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = 0.5$
>
> $f'(x) < 0$ when $x<-0.5$
>
> $f''(x) > 0$ when $-0.5<x<5 \cap 5<x<6 \cap x>6$

I broke it down to this graph, but my problem is that if I change the scaling to fix the points that don't line up (the y-intercept and the ($2$, $0.5$)), the horizontal asymptote moves as well. How can you scale the short-term behavior without affecting the long-term behavior?

[Desmos graph link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bubiiux6rk)

I also tried adding factors to the top and bottom that take the form $x^2 + a$ that way no roots are added but you can add factors, but it hasn't worked out nicely for me yet.

Update:
I had a minor breakthrough with multiplying the original function I had in Desmos by $\frac{x^2 +a}{x^2 +2a}$, and then I increased a to approach $+\infty$, which seemed to work. However, I'm not sure I'm allowed to write $\lim_{a \to +\infty}$ on this question for a rational function, so how would I go about rewriting this without having to introduce a limit?